# "Something came up" in Japanese

Tags: translation, idioms

I always use this in English to excuse myself from a planned meeting/meet up (professional or personal).
Basically, I don't want to bother the interlocutor with the details and notify them I am busy.

I am not happy with what I can currently produce:

- 新しい予定があります
- いけなくなりました

Could you suggest more natural ways and idiomatic ways to express the same idea?

Comment: 急事ができました also works.

Comment: @user5185 http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/54991/m0u/

Comment: @oldergod I know it's in a dictionary. Are you saying 急事 is more common than 急用？ Do you think きゅうじができました would be understood as 急(な用)事ができました in daily conversation?

Comment: I don't really know about this. 急事 is something someone taught me when I asked the question the OP is asking to a coworker few years ago. To tell you the truth, because the kanji do not come up right away when typing, I think it's rather rarely used. I also used it in an email so I don't know if it is really used in speaking. For daily conversation, Electeur's answer is good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More natural expressions would include:

「ちょっと[用事]{ようじ}（or 用）ができてしまって。」

「[急]{きゅう}に[予定]{よてい}が[入]{はい}ってしまって。」

It would be nice to say 「すみません（が）」 or 「ごめんなさい」 at the beginning.

Informally, one could replace 「てしまって」 with 「ちゃって」.  In business settings, I recommend the former.

The ambiguous 「って/て」 ending is very common with these little expressions.

Comment: Or even a 「申し訳ございません」 if the meeting is with a client / boss.

Comment: (I'm aware I'm nitpicking, but...) wouldn't 「てしまいまして」 be more appropriate for most business situations?

Answer (score 2):

You can also be a bit more vague with the

> いろいろあって、参加できなくなってしまいました。

and add the appropriate amount of apologies.

いろいろ　tends to imply something that you don't really want to talk about so you almost certainly won't be asked.

Comment: This should be あって, not 合って.

Comment: @dinogeist Quite right. Sorry about that.